# Convert Excel data list to matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would be grateful if someone can help me. I have a list of board directors and the companies they are directors in.
My Excel data list is quite large, and here is an example of how it look like.

```
Name of director    Companies
A                   Company 1   Company 4   
B                   Company 1   Company 2   Company 3
C                   Company 4
```

I need to convert it to a matrix table like this

```
Company 1   Company 2   Company 3   Company 4
A   1             0            0                1
B   1             1            1                0
C   0             0            0                1
```

Any ideas, how can I Do this?

Comment: Easy with a VBA macro

Answer (score 2):

#### New Sheet with Desired Layout

**Original Layout**
[image]

**New Sheet - List all Companies in Row 1, one per column, Starting in Column B**

[image]

Formulas:

A2 `=OrigSheet!$A2`

- *Cell with First Director Name on Original Data Sheet*

B2 `=IFNA(1*(MATCH(B$1,OrigSheet!$B2:$Z2,0)>0),)`

- `B$1` *Header Cell of this Formula's Column (contains a company name)*
- `OrigSheet!$B2:$Z2` *Company Cells on the original data sheet for the

  director on the row in formula A2. Adjust column `Z` as needed.*

Drag/Copy B2 Right until under the last Company Name

- Max companies, Column `Z` in the formula.

Select Row 2 formulas starting with A2 and drag down.

Variations:
`=IFNA(1*(MATCH(B$1,OrigSheet!$B2:$Z2,0)>0),"")` - No zeros.
`=IFNA(MATCH(B$1,OrigSheet!$B2:$Z2,0)>0,FALSE)` - True & False
`=IFNA(MATCH(B$1,OrigSheet!$B2:$Z2,0)>0,"")` - True only
`=IFNA(IF(MATCH(B$1,OrigSheet!$B2:$Z2,0),"yes"),"")` - "yes" only